# Disable input in a table row depending on a selection

Tags: jquery

I have a table with rows being added dynamically, each row has same select and input, I would like to disable an input with class "di" on each row depending on the value selected... This if i select "Draft COA" an input in the same row of class di is disabled else not....

here is the table

```
............
<tr>
    <td class="tg-ugh9">
<select name="activity[]" class="activity">
<option value="">-- Select Activity --</option>
<option value="Issuing">Analysis</option>
<option value="Analysis">Supervision</option>
<option value="Review">Review</option>
<option value="Draft COA">Draft COA</option>
<option value="COA Approval">COA Approval</option>
</select>
</td>


<td class="tg-ugh9">
<input id="dp1415022676235" class="date di hasDatepicker" name="datei[]" type="text">
</td>

<td class="tg-ugh9">
<input id="dp1415022676236" class="date dr hasDatepicker" name="dater[]" type="text">
</td>

<td><a href="#remove_row" id="remove_row"> -Remove</a></td>
</tr><tr><td colspan="3"></td><td></td><td colspan="3"><input id="save_su" value="Submit" class="submit-button" type="button"></td></tr>
```

here is what i have so far, problem is the function happens on all rows despite the selected value

```
   $(document).on('change','.activity',function(){
            value =$('.activity option:selected').val();
            $('#sample_req').val(id);
            if(value == 'Draft COA'){
               $(this).closest('tr').find('.di').prop('disabled','disabled').val('N/A') ;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should determine `value` like this: `value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();`  Otherwise you are getting value for first activity class with any option selected. Also where is `#sample_req` and what is value for `id`?

Comment: `value = $(this).val();` is ok also.

Comment: It still does not work, what it should do is in row one, if i select 'Draft COA' it should disable and in row 2 if i select any other value, it should not disable...

Comment: So please rewrite your question. I do not understand. Do you want, if in all rows are `Draft COA` then all first input should be disabled, and if in any row it's not `Draft COA` then release everywhere? Not clear to me.

Comment: Do you need this? http://jsfiddle.net/bhjaz3Lw/

Comment: Now you are talking, exactly that, so i was just missing the else if.. thank man